# EditText content in RecyclerView dissappearing and jumping around

Tags: android, arraylist, android-edittext, android-recyclerview

I'm having lots of trouble with this, and I can find things related to my issue through a search, but they don't seem to fix my issue, and I've tried everything I can. I can't seem to fix this issue for the life of me.

So I have an app to track college courses. In which, I have a button to add a custom view holder to a RecyclerView. This custom view holder contains two EditText field along with a CheckBox. Now, when I click my button to "Add Course", it will add those three things. That works just fine. However, when I enter any text into either EditText field, and then add another course, it erases all content previously entered into the EditText fields. I am trying to save this content, pretty much permanently, or at least until the user deletes that view (either clicking my "Erase All" button, or swiping it to the left). I'm having extreme difficulty with this though. I've been trying to add a "TextChangedListener" to each view, but I cannot seem to get this to work. I've tried making a custom text listener and adding it in my "onCreateViewHolder" method, and then setting the text in the "onBindViewHolder" method, but this does not seem to solve my issue.

My other issue, which I believe is probably related to that one, occurs when I have enough views in the RecyclerView to scroll down, and I enter text into an EditText field. Then, when I scroll down, the text I entered will appear in other EditText fields. Or if I check my CheckBox, then scroll down, then other check boxes will be checked as well. Here are some pictures for a visual.

Here is when I add a new course, and the text disappears:

[image: Here is when I add a new course, and the text disappears.]

Here is my scrolling issue:

[image: Here is my scrolling issue.]

Here are my files, also.

First, my MainActivity.java:

```
import android.content.ClipData;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.helper.ItemTouchHelper;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ArrayList<ListItems> itemsList = new ArrayList<ListItems>();
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private MyRecyclerAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // For the recycler view.
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        final LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        final RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl);

        // For the addCourse button.
        final Button addCourse = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addCourse);
        addCourse.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ListItems.createListItem(itemsList);
                adapter = new MyRecyclerAdapter(MainActivity.this, itemsList);
                mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
            }
        });

        final Button clearAll = (Button) findViewById(R.id.clearAll);
        clearAll.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // In order to clear the list.
                adapter.clearAdapter();
            }
        });

        // For the drag and drop/swipe to dismiss.
        ItemTouchHelper itemTouchHelper = new ItemTouchHelper(
                new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(ItemTouchHelper.UP | ItemTouchHelper.DOWN,
                        ItemTouchHelper.LEFT) {
                    public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
                        final int fromPos = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
                        final int toPos = target.getAdapterPosition();
                        Collections.swap(itemsList, fromPos, toPos);
                        adapter.notifyItemMoved(fromPos, toPos);
                        return true;
                    }
                    public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
                       adapter.onItemDismiss(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
                    }
                });
        itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(mRecyclerView);
    } // End of onCreate
} // End of MainActivity
```

Now, my adapter:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.helper.ItemTouchHelper;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class MyRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomRowViewHolder> {

     private ArrayList<ListItems> itemsList;
     private Context mContext;
     private int focuseditem = 0;
     String afterTextChanged = "";


    public MyRecyclerAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ListItems> itemsList){
        this.itemsList = itemsList;
        this.mContext = context;
    }

     @Override
     public CustomRowViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(final ViewGroup viewGroup, int position) {
         View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.new_course_row, null);
         final CustomRowViewHolder holder = new CustomRowViewHolder(v, new CustomTextListener());

         holder.creditsText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
         holder.checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {
                 if(holder.checkBox.isChecked()) {
                     holder.courseText.setEnabled(false);
                     holder.courseText.setFocusable(false);
                     holder.courseText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
                     holder.creditsText.setEnabled(false);
                     holder.creditsText.setFocusable(false);
                     holder.creditsText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
                 } else {
                     holder.courseText.setEnabled(true);
                     holder.courseText.setFocusable(true);
                     holder.courseText.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
                     holder.courseText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
                     holder.creditsText.setEnabled(true);
                     holder.creditsText.setFocusable(true);
                     holder.creditsText.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
                     holder.creditsText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
                 } // End if else
             }
         });
         return holder;
     } // End of onCreateViewHolder

     @Override
     public void onBindViewHolder(final CustomRowViewHolder customRowViewHolder, int position) {
         ListItems listItem = itemsList.get(position);
         customRowViewHolder.itemView.setSelected(focuseditem == position);
         customRowViewHolder.getLayoutPosition();
         customRowViewHolder.customTextListener.updatePosition(position, customRowViewHolder);
         customRowViewHolder.courseText.setText(itemsList.get(position).getCourse());
     } // End of onBindViewHolder

     public void clearAdapter() {
         itemsList.clear();
         notifyDataSetChanged();
     } // End of clearAdapter

     public int getItemCount() {
         return(null != itemsList ? itemsList.size() : 0);
     } // End of getItemCount

     public void onItemDismiss(int position) {
         itemsList.remove(position);
         notifyItemRemoved(position);
         notifyItemRangeChanged(position, itemsList.size());
     } // End of onItemDismiss

     public void onItemMove(List<ListItems> itemsList, int fromPosition, int toPosition) {
         Collections.swap(itemsList, fromPosition, toPosition);
         notifyItemMoved(fromPosition, toPosition);
     } // End of onItemMove

} // End of MyRecyclerAdapter

/**
 * Created by Thomas on 6/3/2016.
 */
class CustomTextListener implements TextWatcher {
    private int position;
    private CustomRowViewHolder customRowViewHolder;

    public void updatePosition(int position, CustomRowViewHolder customRowViewHolder) {
        this.position = position;
        this.customRowViewHolder = customRowViewHolder;
    }
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        customRowViewHolder.courseText.setText(s.toString());
    }
}
```

My "CustomRowViewHolder.java":

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class CustomRowViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    protected EditText courseText;
    protected EditText creditsText;
    protected CheckBox checkBox;
    protected RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
    protected CustomTextListener customTextListener;

    public CustomRowViewHolder(View view, CustomTextListener customTextListener) {
        super(view);
        this.customTextListener = customTextListener;
        this.courseText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.course);
        this.creditsText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.credits);
        this.checkBox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.complete);
        this.relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.relLayout);

        view.setClickable(true);
    }
}
```

Lastly, my "ListItems.java":

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ListItems {
    private String course;
    private String credits;
    private Boolean complete;

    public ListItems(String mCourse, String mCredits, Boolean mComplete) {
        course = mCourse;
        credits = mCredits;
        complete = mComplete;
    }

    public String getCourse() {
        return course;
    }

    public void setCourse(String course) {
        this.course = course;
    }

    public String getCredits() {
        return credits;
    }

    public void setCredits(String credits) {
        this.credits = credits;
    }

    public Boolean getIsComplete() {
        return complete;
    }

    public void setIsComplete(Boolean complete) {
        this.complete = complete;
    }

    public static ArrayList<ListItems> createListItem(ArrayList<ListItems> itemsList) {
        itemsList.add(new ListItems(null, null, false));
        return itemsList;
    } // End of createListItem

    public static ArrayList<ListItems> removeListItem(ArrayList<ListItems> itemsList) {
        if (itemsList.size() == 0) {
            return itemsList;
        } else {
            itemsList.remove(0);
        } // End if

        return itemsList;
    } // End of removeListItem
} // End of ListItems
```

Thank you in advance to any help at all! It's greatly appreciated, as I've been stuck on this issue for a very long time!

Comment: You need to maintain list of yourEditText contents..!!
!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem... You could try to add a field in ListItems with the text from ediText (or a different list if you want). Important is to have a reference to the previous inserted text and the listItem. Let's say, on Check if complete, get the text and set it to that field from ListItem.

And then, in adapter, setText to editText with the value of that field.

Answer (score 0):

add method to your recyclers view to inserting new item . or removing them.
like that

```
public void addItem(ListItems object)
{
    itemsList.add(object);
    int pos = itemsList.indexOf(object);
    notifyItemInserted(pos);
}
```

and then in your add course button click event call add item method :

```
 // For the recycler view.
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    final LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new  LinearLayoutManager(this);
    final RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl);

         List<ListItems> itemsList = new ArrayList<>();
        adapter = new MyRecyclerAdapter(MainActivity.this, itemsList);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

    // For the addCourse button.
    final Button addCourse = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addCourse);
    addCourse.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mRecyclerView.getAdapter().addItem(new ListItems(null, null, false));

        }
    });
```

for you second issue just save state of check Box in related ListItem then set it to check box in onBindViewHolder method: like this:

```
@Override
 public void onBindViewHolder(final CustomRowViewHolder customRowViewHolder, int position) {
     ListItems listItem = itemsList.get(position);
     customRowViewHolder.itemView.setSelected(focuseditem == position);
     customRowViewHolder.getLayoutPosition();
     customRowViewHolder.customTextListener.updatePosition(position, customRowViewHolder);
     customRowViewHolder.courseText.setText(itemsList.get(position).getCourse());

    // just set listener to check box.
  customRowViewHolder.checkBox.setChecked(  itemsList.get(position).getIsComplete());
initEditText(customRowViewHolder,itemsList.get(position).getIsComplete());
    customRowViewHolder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
           itemsList.get(position).setIsComplete(b);

 // for retrieve eidtTexts state
  initEditText(customRowViewHolder,b);
    });



     //for retrieve text 
     customRowViewHolder.courseText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            itemsList.get(position).setCourse(editable.toString());
        }
    });

customRowViewHolder.creditsText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            itemsList.get(position).setCredits(editable.toString());
        }
    });

 customRowViewHolder.courseText.setText( itemsList.get(position).getCourse());
 customRowViewHolder.creditsText.setText( itemsList.get(position).getCredits());

 } // End of onBindViewHolder

 private void initEditText(CustomRowViewHolder customRowViewHolder,boolean b) {
    if(b) {
        customRowViewHolder.courseText.setEnabled(false);
        customRowViewHolder.courseText.setFocusable(false);
        customRowViewHolder.courseText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
        customRowViewHolder.creditsText.setEnabled(false);
        customRowViewHolder.creditsText.setFocusable(false);
        customRowViewHolder.creditsText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
    } else {
        customRowViewHolder.courseText.setEnabled(true);
        customRowViewHolder.courseText.setFocusable(true);
        customRowViewHolder.courseText.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        customRowViewHolder.courseText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
        customRowViewHolder.creditsText.setEnabled(true);
        customRowViewHolder.creditsText.setFocusable(true);
        customRowViewHolder.creditsText.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        customRowViewHolder.creditsText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
    } // End if else
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm not sure what did it, but I moved my "createListItem" method into my adapter, as well as moved all the code that I had inside my addCourse button click, I moved all that (except for where I actually add the course) outside of the button click. Now, my first problem is solved! Although, I am still having issues with the scrolling. When I scroll down after checking a check box and typing in an EditText field, other check boxes will be filled and the content I typed in will dissappear.

Comment: Your check box solution also worked for me! Thank you so much again! I'm still having one more bug I need to chase though. For some reason when I enter input into a course field or credits field, and then I scroll down, and scroll back up, the content has disappeared. Not only that but when I check a check box, the text fields are supposed to disable, which they do. But if I check a check box and then scroll down then back up, the text fields are no longer disabled, but the check box is still checked.